# Qt: Qt Designer button panel error

Tags: qt

I've created a modal dialog named 'new_dialog' with ok/cancel buttons. Now I want to work on slot for the OK button. I right-click on the button pane, select "Go to slot" command from context menu; and get an error:

> Couldn't find class with Ui::new_dialog in mainwindow.cpp. Check
>   include directives
>   (this is a translation into English)

How can I assign a slot to the button?

Thanks!

Some code:

There is new.ui and ui_new.h, directive in mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "ui_new.h"
```

The dialog is called from mainwindow:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QDialog *new_dialog = new QDialog(0,0);
    Ui_New newUi;
    newUi.setupUi(new_dialog);
    new_dialog->exec();
}
```

ui_new.h:

```
#ifndef UI_NEW_H
#define UI_NEW_H

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtGui/QAction>
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QButtonGroup>
#include <QtGui/QDialog>
#include <QtGui/QDialogButtonBox>
#include <QtGui/QHeaderView>
#include <QtGui/QLabel>
#include <QtGui/QLineEdit>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_New
{
public:
    QDialogButtonBox *buttonBox;
    QLabel *label;
    QLabel *label_2;
    QLineEdit *lineEdit;
    QLineEdit *lineEdit_2;

    void setupUi(QDialog *new_dialog)
    {
        if (new_dialog->objectName().isEmpty())
            new_dialog->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("Dialog"));
        new_dialog->setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
        new_dialog->resize(250, 180);
        new_dialog->setModal(false);
        buttonBox = new QDialogButtonBox(new_dialog);
        buttonBox->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("buttonBox"));
        buttonBox->setGeometry(QRect(40, 140, 181, 32));
        buttonBox->setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);
        buttonBox->setStandardButtons(QDialogButtonBox::Cancel|QDialogButtonBox::Ok);
        label = new QLabel(new_dialog);
        label->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("label"));
        label->setGeometry(QRect(20, 40, 46, 13));
        label_2 = new QLabel(new_dialog);
        label_2->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("label_2"));
        label_2->setGeometry(QRect(20, 70, 46, 13));
        lineEdit = new QLineEdit(new_dialog);
        lineEdit->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("lineEdit"));
        lineEdit->setGeometry(QRect(70, 40, 113, 20));
        lineEdit_2 = new QLineEdit(new_dialog);
        lineEdit_2->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("lineEdit_2"));
        lineEdit_2->setGeometry(QRect(70, 70, 113, 20));

        retranslateUi(new_dialog);
        QObject::connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(accepted()), new_dialog, SLOT(accept()));
        QObject::connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(rejected()), new_dialog, SLOT(reject()));

        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(new_dialog);
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QDialog *new_dialog)
    {
        new_dialog->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("Dialog", "New person", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
        label->setText(QApplication::translate("Dialog", "Name", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
        label_2->setText(QApplication::translate("Dialog", "Surname", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
    } // retranslateUi

};

namespace Ui {
    class new_dialog: public Ui_New {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // UI_NEW_H
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you create new Dialog class inheriting from QDialog ?? Generally if you are using QDialog , you can not connect to button slot but have to connect to accepted() or rejected() signal to any of the slots of MainWindow.

```
QDialog *new_dialog = new QDialog(0,0);
connect(new_dialog,SIGNAL(accepted()),this,SLOT(MySlot()));
```

Note: **this** is mainwindow pointer

If you create your own Dialog class and has pointers to button , first connect the Button clicked() to dialog slot and then redirect to MainWindow from there .